# ListView with TextView only centers text that wraps

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a LinearLayout with a title TextView at the top and then a ListView that contains TextViews.  This is next to another Similar LinearLayout that has a GridView in it.

The TextViews in the ListView will not center unless the text wraps due to being long.

I did have them centered when I hardwired the width of the ListView, however that had another side effect, which was that the text was cut off on both ends of long lines, even if it wrapped.  Just didn't wrap properly.  So I fixed that by moving the hard coded width up to the enclosing LinearLayout, but now have this issue.

An interesting note is that my similar GridView does not seem to have the issue, although it does also have a 'background drawable' which is a rectangle with rounded corners.

The Layout is:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/course_part"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/course"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_course_title"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_course"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

And the TextView that populates the ListView is:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/list_item_mark_name_name"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:fontFamily="Roboto"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:text="name"
      android:textColor="#ff000000"
      android:textSize="@dimen/text_course_grid"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:typeface="monospace"
/>
```

And I should note that I dynamically change the font size in my ArrayAdapter 'getView' based on the length of the text:

```
    // First shrink it's size to better fit.
    float textSize = 30;    // In DP units.
    int nameLength = mark.name.length();
    if (nameLength > 4)
    {
        if (nameLength <= 8)
            textSize *= 4.0f / nameLength;  // Up to 8, proportionally shrink it.
        else
            textSize *= 0.5f;               // After 8, leave it at half size.
    }

    holder.textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, textSize);
    holder.textView.setMinHeight(this.textViewPixels);
    holder.textView.setText(mark.name); // Set it's name.
    holder.textView.setTextColor(appData.getNightMode() ? Color.WHITE : Color.BLACK);  // Just added it.  Set it's color properly.
```

I have tried gravity="center' and textAlignment="center" and they both behave the same.

I have tried various combinations of match_parent and fill_parent on the various containing views/layouts with usually bad results, and if I don't hardwire the width, I get either far too much space or a really thin useless column.

Thanks!

Comment: try android:gravity="center_horizontal"

Comment: Tried it. No joy.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:  Just changed the enclosing LinearLayout to a RelativeLayout.

Why this works is a good question.  Smells like a bug in the libraries.

So here is my updated layout, changed slightly to get the title TextView to center up.  No change to the TextView used in the ListView.

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/course_part"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/course_course_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/course"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_course_title"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_course"
            android:layout_below="@id/course_course_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```